# Hotel using array

Tags: java, arrays

Okay basically I am creating a hotel which acts the following options

```
System.out.println("V: To View all rooms");
System.out.println("A: To Add customer to a room");
System.out.println("E: To Display empty rooms");
System.out.println("D: To Delete customer from a room");
System.out.println("F: Find room from customer name");
System.out.println("O: View rooms alphabetically by name");
```

- NOW, I am able to do the VIEW, ADD CUSTOMER, DISPLAY EMPTY ROOMS AND DELETE".
- HOWEVER,  I just realised I cannot add multiple customers. The code will simply assign a customer with the same name to each room chosen.

Example: If I add the name TOM  to room 2, and then later add DENNIS to room 3.
Room 2 and Room 3 which show that it is occupied by Dennis.
 - I know why, because the String customer can only store one information.

*I have a feeling I need to change Customer to an Array.*

**(please bare in mind, I don't want to use an ArrayList).**

**SO: my question is, how do I go about solving this? Because I tried to work with Customer as an array and I ruined the entire coding (thankgod for local history revert!)**

Code:

```
package testroom;

import java.util.*;

public class TestRoom{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String Customer = null;
        int roomNum = 1;
        String Option;

        String[] hotel = new String[12];

        initialise(hotel); 

        while ( roomNum  < 11 )
        {

            System.out.println("Hotel Booking Options");
            System.out.println("V: To View all rooms");
            System.out.println("A: To Add customer to a room");
            System.out.println("E: To Display empty rooms");
            System.out.println("D: To Delete customer from a room");
            System.out.println("F: Find room from customer name");
            System.out.println("O: View rooms alphabetically by name");

            Option = input.next();

            if (Option.equals("V")){ //viewing all rooms
                view(hotel, Customer);  
            }

            if (Option.equals("A")){ // adding a customer to a room

                System.out.println("Enter room number(1-10)");
                roomNum =input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum + " : " ) ;
                Customer = input.next();
                hotel[roomNum] = Customer ;
                add(hotel, Customer);
                System.out.println(" ");

            }

            if (Option.equals("E")){ //view all empty rooms
                vacant(hotel, Customer); //links to private static void empty
            }

            if (Option.equals("D")){ //Deletes a customer from a room

                //Searches if room is occupied, if it is then it will delete customer from that room
                view(hotel, Customer);
                System.out.println("Enter the room which you want to delete a customer from: ");
                roomNum = input.nextInt();
                hotel[roomNum] = "empty";

                delete(hotel, Customer);
                System.out.println("");

            }

            if (Option.equals("F")){ //view all empty rooms
                find(hotel); //links to private static void empty
            }

        }
    }

    private static void initialise( String hotelRef[] )
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++ )
            hotelRef[x] = "empty";
        System.out.println( "Welcome to The Plaza");
    }


    public static void view(String hotel[], String Customer){

        for (int x =1; x <11; x++)
        {
            int z=0;
            String Customername = Customer;
            hotel[z]= Customername;

            if (hotel[x].equals("empty"))
                System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
            else {
                System.out.println("room " + x + " is occupied by "+ hotel[z]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void add(String hotel[], String Customer){
        for (int x =1; x <11; x++)
        {
            int z=0;
            String Customername = Customer;
            hotel[z]= Customername;
            if (hotel[x].equals("empty"))
                System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
            else {
                System.out.println("room " + x + " is occupied by "+ hotel[z]);
            }

        }
    }

    private static void vacant(String hotel[], String Customer){
        for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++ )
        {
            int z=0;
            String Customername = Customer;
            hotel[z]= Customername;
            if (hotel[x].equals("empty")) //if statement
                System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty"); 
        }

    }


    private static void delete(String hotel[], String Customer){ //link to this when pressed the D key
        //view (hotel);
        for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++ )
        {
            int z=0;
            String Customername = Customer;
            hotel[z]= Customername;
            if (hotel[x].equals("empty"))
            { 
                System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("room " + x + " occupied by " + hotel[x]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void find(String hotel[]){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("Enter customer name for room:" );
        String customersname;
        customersname = input.next();  //stores name they enter as customers name
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++ )
        {
            if (hotel[x].equals(customersname))
                System.out.println("room " + x + " is occupied                       by "+hotel[x]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I've just edited my post.

Comment: Can you please format your code better when you post?

Comment: @ShaziaE: Your code is very badly indented, so it took me a while to edit it. In the time that I was editing, you edited the question, so it was overwritten. I have re-added it back.

Comment: @ShaziaE: Next time, please indent your code before posting. There are plenty of editors that can do this for you. I don't know how you can read your own code when you are programming without proper indentation.

Comment: I'd also recommend a read through the Java Code Conventions for naming. (Hint: Starting a variable with a capital letter is a __very bad__ idea). Also, you may want to look into an object oriented approach for this, as Java is after all an object oriented language. Think about it like this: instead of just saving the name of the last customer entered, save another `Customer` _object_ (you haven't made this yet, you should) into a list of them. Then you save all of them. Look at Roney's answer for an example on a simple `Customer` object.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is that you are not instantiating the class for each new entry. I'm sorry, but there is just too much fundamentally wrong with this question. What you need to do would be to just define the Customer class with its data members and data access functions in it and then create new objects as necessary and populate/utilize them from another class entirely.

You could try something like this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Customer
{
    private String name;
    private int room;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setRoom(int room)
    {
        this.room=room;
    }

    public int getRoom()
    {
        return this.room;
    }
}

class Hotel
{
    public static void initialize(Customer RoomList[])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
        {
            RoomList[i]=new Customer();
            RoomList[i].setName("EMPTY");
            RoomList[i].setRoom(i+1);
        }
    }

    public static void viewList(Customer RoomList[])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
        {
            if(RoomList[i].getName()=="EMPTY")
                System.out.println("Room number "+RoomList[i].getRoom()+" is vacant.");
            else
                System.out.println("Room number "+RoomList[i].getRoom()+" is ocupied by "+RoomList[i].getName()+".");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean addCustomer(Customer RoomList[], String name)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName().equals("EMPTY"))
            {
                RoomList[i].setName(name);
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    public static void showEmptyRooms(Customer RoomList[])
    {
        System.out.println("Available rooms are:");
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName()=="EMPTY")
                System.out.println(RoomList[i].getRoom());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean deleteCustomer(Customer RoomList[], String name)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName().equals(name))
            {
                RoomList[i].setName("EMPTY");
                System.out.println("Deletion successful.\n");
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    public static int getIndex(Customer RoomList[], String name)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName().equals(name))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Customer[] RoomList = new Customer[12];
        String name;
        initialize(RoomList);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option=0;

        do
        {
            System.out.println("        Hotel Booking Options");
            System.out.println("=====================================");
            System.out.println("1: To View all rooms");
            System.out.println("2: To Add customer to a room");
            System.out.println("3: To Display empty rooms");
            System.out.println("4: To Delete customer from a room");
            System.out.println("5: Find room from customer name");
            System.out.println("0: Exit");

            System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
            option = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    viewList(RoomList);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    System.out.print("Customer's name: ");
                    name=input.next();
                    System.out.println();
                    if(!addCustomer(RoomList, name))
                        System.out.println("No rooms available!");
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    showEmptyRooms(RoomList);
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    System.out.print("Customer's name: ");
                    name=input.next();
                    System.out.println();
                    deleteCustomer(RoomList, name);
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                {
                    System.out.print("Customer's name: ");
                    name=input.next();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Customer's room: "+RoomList[getIndex(RoomList, name)].getRoom()+"\n");
                    break;
                }
                case 0:
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThank you!\n");
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid option!\n");
                    break;
                }
            }


        }while(option!=0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see.. I'm new to Java so still have a lot to learn. but thank you

Comment: @ShaziaE: Try to understand the new code I just added. Try making up something along the same lines. I hope this helps.

Comment: @ShaziaE A review for object oriented programming would be useful in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be slightly incorrect. Look at the add customer code. No matter where you add the customer, it also adds to index zero. :)

```
 if (Option.equals("A")){ // adding a customer to a room
    System.out.println("Enter room number(1-10)");
    roomNum =input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum + " : " ) ;
    Customer = input.next();
    hotel[roomNum] = Customer ; // adds to the room number.
    add(hotel, Customer); // adds to the zero-th index.
    System.out.println(" ");
 }


private static void add(String hotel[], String Customer){
    for (int x =1; x <11; x++)
    {
        int z=0;
        String Customername = Customer;
        hotel[z]= Customername; // this line is the culprit.
        if (hotel[x].equals("empty"))
            System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
        else {
            System.out.println("room " + x + " is occupied by "+ hotel[z]);
        }

    }
}
```